# Using Rails 3.1 :as => :admin for updating attributes protected by attr_accessible

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, mass-assignment, attr-accessible

After reading about [attr_accessible in the Rails 3.1 API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods.html#method-i-attr_accessible), I see that there is an as `:admin` option in there. I would like to know two things.

1. If the user has an admin flag, how do does my controller tell my model that the user is an admin.
2. If the user is an owner, can i specify `:as => owner` in my model, and once again how does my controller inform my model they are the owner of an item.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is no built-in integration with models; you pass in the role in the `assign_attributes` call:

```
@project.assign_attributes(params[:project], :as => :admin)
```

The `:as` parameter defaults to `:default`, and you can pass in any symbol that you want. To integrate this into your `User` model, you could give it an attribute called `role`, and then do something like:

```
@project.assign_attributes(params[:project], :as => current_user.role.to_sym)
```

You can also bypass the protection using `:without_protection`:

```
@project.assign_attributes(params[:project], :without_protection => true)
```

In a similar way, `new`, `create`, `create!`, `update_attributes`, and `update_attributes!` methods all respect mass-assignment security. The [Ruby on Rails guide on security](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html) has [more info](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#countermeasures).

Comment: I have a question though. I'm upgrading a Rails 4 up to 5 (which was previously on Rails 3. and I came across something like `@project.update_attributes(params[:project], :as => current_user.role.to_sym)` but but i get an error that says `update_attributes` accepts only one argument. What happened to the `as: :admin` part of this code? is it safe to remove it completely?

Answer (score 3):

For both scenarios, you'd pass it in the same way that you declare it originally.  So for example:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  attr_accessible :credit_card, :as => :admin
end
```

If you did

```
user = User.new(:name => "John", :credit_card => "1234123412341234")
```

Then you won't be able to assign the `credit_card`:

```
user.attributes # {:name => "John", :credit_card => nil}
```

However, if you state that it will be `:as => :admin` then it allows it

```
user = User.new({:name => "John", :credit_card => "1234123412341234"}, :as => :admin)
user.attributes # {:name => "John", :credit_card => "1234123412341234"}
```

More information:

http://www.enlightsolutions.com/articles/whats-new-in-edge-scoped-mass-assignment-in-rails-3-1

Answer (score 1):

all the attributes you want to access as a specific user should be defined properly. For example:

```
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :name
    attr_accessible :credit_card, :as => :admin
    end
```

This showed error for me. 
But when i modied it to

```
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :name
    attr_accessible :name, :credit_card, :as => :admin
    end
```

This worked fine when i used

```
    @user.update_attributes(params[:user], :as => :admin)
```