# How is active admin/rails admin useful if they cannot circumvent mass assignment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I can't create an object with a user_id with active admin because user_id is protected. If I leave user_id out of attr_accessible then the object is not secure.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8796827/using-rails-3-1-as-admin-for-updating-attributes-protected-by-attr-accessib

Comment: Link is interesting but does not solve the problem. It would if I was rolling my own admin interface. It does not look like active admin uses the ":as => :admin" feature.

Answer (score 1):

ActiveAdmin use InheritedResource, so you can use `with_role` class method for each controller,

Check https://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources/issues/151

To setup all by default try

```
# config/initializers/active_admin.rb
module ActiveAdmin
  class BaseController
    with_role :admin
  end
end
```

BTW good article about this problem http://ejholmes.github.com/2012/04/22/handling-mass-assignment-with-active-admin.html